# In DDD, is Comment included in Post Aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Sorry for poor English.

When learning about DDD , i have a question about aggregate.

In `Board` domain, we have two entity, One is `Post`, another is `Comment`.

I think `Comment` can't exist without `Post`. So I think `Comment` should be in `Post` Aggregate and `Board` domain has one aggregate which root is `Post`.

But from a different perspective, entities in the same aggregate have same life cycle,
so `Comment` life cycle is different from `Post`'s life cycle,
and modifying `Post` doesn't affect `Comment` and vice versa.

So `Board` domain has two aggregate,

one is aggregate which root is `Comment` and another is aggregate which root is `Post`

This two think makes me feeling mess.

Comment: Every time I asked myself about this domens aggregates and entities, i just thought in way of relationships in the tables :D  Its should be many to one relationship. In ur case with posts and comment,  imho it is right that post is aggregate root and comment is a entity, because if u delete post, comment cant exist. Also u can add a lot of comment to 1 post, and same comments cant exist for different posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been there before, and I learned it the hard way. At first, it seems natural to have the comments part of the post aggregate but here are the limitations you might face with this design.

- It can happen that you need to delete the post and keep the comments. Same as you see on some social media platforms.
- A post can have a lot of comments to the point that it becomes expensive to load them all in memory each time you fetch a post.
- Users can interact with comments directly (reactions, comment on a comment, share, mention other users ...) hence it is easier if the comment can be uniquely identified across the system.
- You might need to list all comments of a user. It becomes harder when the comment is part of the post aggregate.

It is safer to have PostComment as a separate aggregate and keep a reference of the post. And as a general rule for designing aggregates, you should keep them as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to read this brilliant article. That changes your perspective to aggregate design rules.

[Effective Aggregate Design Part I: Modeling a Single Aggregate](https://www.dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_1.pdf)